# PHP - Get colour input value

Tags: javascript, php

I'm currently making a form that includes a few dynamicly added `<input type='color'>` fields, and I want to post their values to another php file.

How could I achieve this? Is it possible to do without JavaScript?

Sample input:

```
<input name='ID From database' type='color' id='colorpicker' value='value from DB'>
```

The JS:

```
var color = $('#colorpicker').val();
colorpicker = $('#colorpicker');
$('#colorpicker').on('change', function() {
  colorpicker.value(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Did you event tried something ??

Comment: I've tried getting the value with javascript, but it might fail because i will have multiple instances of that input field @Connum

Comment: Post your code to get help.

Comment: And why should multiple input fields be a problem for a Javascript solution? Besides that, yes, of course it is possible on the php after submitting the form. But what exactly do you want people to do, write the code for you?

Comment: @Connum, I posted the code that i tried using above, but the problem is that there are multiple instances of that objects and using ids is not the best solution, also I tried looking for pure php solution but couldn't find any

Comment: Use a class for the fields and use that class for `.on`, but the question is, what do you exactly want to do with `colorpicker.value`?

Comment: the color picker value would get posted to a php file

Comment: and @CharlotteDunois, if i used a class wouldn't it affect every input field with the same class?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you try to do. Can you please explain what you want to do?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, edited the question, hope it's clearer for you now

Comment: You can just post their values as the field is. You don't need any Javascript. The browser will send the values, all you need to do is handle the data correctly on the PHP side. You might want to dump the POST superglobal variable to look at the received data.

Comment: I just tested that, I got the hex code of the colour I picked.

Comment: oops yeah seems to be my bad, there was a mistake in my php code @CharlotteDunois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could submit the Hex value by setting the value of a hidden input with an onclick function containing:

```
      document.getElementById('colorpicker_value').value = document.getElementById('colorpicker').value;
```

or put

```
      colorpicker_value.value(this.value);
```

into your script to set the value of a hidden input if you don't want to take the value directly from the colorpicker -

```
      <input type="hidden" name="colorpicker_value"/>
```

or you can give the colorpicker a "name" `name="colorpicker"` so you can pick up its value directly as a `$_POST['colorpicker']` variable as per the comments above.

You can preload the values if you know them at the point where the page is delivered from PHP:

```
      <input type="color" class="colorpicker" name="colorpicker<?php echo htmlspecialchars($unique_number); ?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value_from_DB); ?>">
```

Assuming the values from your DB are Hex values.

If you have multiple colorpickers to submit, as long as you give each one a unique name you will be able to collect their values independently in PHP irrespective of their class or ID.

Then you could look up the Hex value by converting it to RGB and looking up the values produced using an array as has been demonstrated on these SO answers:

[Function that converts hex color values to an approximate color name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993970/function-that-converts-hex-color-values-to-an-approximate-color-name)

This is a link to an even larger array of values Hex/RGB to Text from [Jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1895094/jake) on the same page - it didn't get many votes but looks like it took him a lot of work.

You might be able to make your own array and look up the Hex values directly using this list of Hex colour names http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp

By the way a colorpicker element does not appear at all in ie8 if that is any concern - it only shows up as a text input - had me puzzled for a while.

Comment: thanks for this, but although it's correct i already found a solution. it was a bug in my action file

Comment: @Deimantas Glad to know that - I had fun pulling it all together.

Answer (score 0):

You will just have to post the data to a php page and then make the inserts into your db.

Example

```
//html page
<form action="receive.php"> 
   <input type="text" name="color1">
   <input type="text" name="color2">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

//php page
<?php
$color1=$_POST['color1'];
$color2=$_POST['color2'];

//the inserts depend on what type of method you want to interact with the db but here is a pdo example

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=YOURHOST;dbname=YOURDB",YOURUSER,YOURPASSWORD);

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO YOURTABLE(color1, color2)
    VALUES(:color1, :color2)");
$statement->execute(array(
    "color1" => $color1,
    "color2" => $color2
));
```

Comment: yes, but the input is type='color', and i want to get the value of that, not type='text'

Comment: and the fields are **dynamically** added