# How to get the name of color from hexadecimal code in java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use openCV for color identification and I get the color in hexadecimal form, like '#FF0000'.
Now I want to convert that to a string.

I have searched a lot, but I didn't find any useful code.
Please help and tell me, if anyone knows the answer.

Comment: Make your own code/name list. I.e.: `#ff0000,Red\n#00ff00,Green\n#0000ff,Blue`. Better store the list as an array or in a database table (for easy searching).

Comment: You can try this:  Color.parseColor("#FF0000")

Comment: there is no name for each color code. Give few examples, what you want to get.

Comment: i dont want any specific color actually my app is detecting a color of an image so how could i specify any color

Comment: i need to know a general code to convert any hex color to string value on run time

Comment: As I already told you, you must provide a list which contains the color codes and their names. That's YOUR business to name all the `16777216` colors (without transparency) or `4294967296` colors (including transparency). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **exact** color name of each hexadecimal color code. So what you need is an **approximation**.

Searching for "approximate color name", I found some usefull links :

- [Name that color](http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/#5B9E47) which provide a js lib.
- [Function that converts hex color values to an approximate color name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993970/function-that-converts-hex-color-values-to-an-approximate-color-name) a php SO question.
- [How can I get the closest color word for a hex color?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-can-i-get-the-closest-color-word-for-a-hex-color) a Graphic Design question that digs deep into the issue.